# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'move'

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

I'm very new to using python and trying to start on my final project for an intro to computing class. I'm using the [Zelle graphics](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) module to try to create a python game. I have created a face using the graphics module, and I want to clone this face and have the cloned version moved 50 spaces to the right. I have imported time in order to move the objects.

Here is the code in question:

```
from graphics import *
```

`import time`

`def main():
    win = GraphWin("Guess the Faces", 1000, 500)
    win.yUp()
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(20, 20, 20))`

```
def robotFaces():
    robot1 = Rectangle(Point(25, 350), Point(100, 425))
    robot1.setOutline(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    robot1.setFill(color_rgb(180, 180, 180))
    robot1.draw(win)
    r1eye1 = Rectangle(Point(35, 390), Point(55, 415))
    r1eye1.setOutline(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    r1eye1.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    r1eye1.draw(win)
    r1eye2 = Rectangle(Point(70, 390), Point(90, 415))
    r1eye2.setOutline(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    r1eye2.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    r1eye2.draw(win)
    r1pupil1 = Rectangle(Point(42, 390), Point(48, 408))
    r1pupil1.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    r1pupil1.draw(win)
    r1pupil2 = Rectangle(Point(77, 390), Point(83, 408))
    r1pupil2.setFill(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    r1pupil2.draw(win)
    r1mouth = Polygon(Point(35, 360), 
        Point(90, 360), 
        Point(90, 370), 
        Point(85, 370), 
        Point(85, 365), 
        Point(40, 365), 
        Point(40, 370), 
        Point(35, 370))
    r1mouth.setFill(color_rgb(255, 255, 255))
    r1mouth.setOutline(color_rgb(0, 0, 0))
    r1mouth.draw(win)

    robot2 = robot1.clone
    robot2.move(50, 0)
    robot2.draw(win)
    r2eye1 = r1eye1.clone
    r2eye1.move(50, 0)
    r2eye1.draw(win)
    r2eye2 = r1eye2.clone
    r2eye2.move(50, 0)
    r2eye2.draw(win)
    r2pupil1 = r1pupil1.clone
    r2pupil1.move(50, 0)
    r2pupil1.draw(win)
    r2pupil2 = r1pupil2.clone
    r2pupil2.move(50, 0)
    r2pupil2.draw(win)
    r2mouth = r1mouth.clone 
    r2mouth.move(50, 0)
    r2mouth.draw(win)

robotFaces()

win.getMouse()
win.promptClose(win.getWidth()/2, 10)
```

`main()`

I expect there to be a second robot face, 50 spaces to the right of the original one.

What actually happens is I get this attribute error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'move'

Is there something else I need to do to make the object movable?

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code instead of using ` or ```

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call the clone method.

```
robot2 = robot1.clone()
```

In future, please cut down your code to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem, and post the full traceback.